# Typing (and executing) expressions with multiple superscripts

Tags: output-formatting, symbolic, input-forms

I am trying to type (and evaluate) expressions of the following form:

$$
G^{a,b}
$$

into a mathematica. I've tried the obvious

```
G^(a, b)
```

or

```
Superscript[G,a,b]
```

But both of these give the same error

```
Syntax::tsntxi: "a,b" is incomplete; more input is needed.
```

I know one solution is to use Symbolize from the Notation package

```
<< Notation`
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SuperscriptBox["G", RowBox[{"_", ",", "_"}]]]]
```

however this solution will not suffice as I want to perform operations such as the following:

```
In[3]:= Sum[G^(a, b), {a, 1, 2}, {b, 1, 2}]
Out[3]= 4 G^(a, b)
```

Is there any sensible way to get around this? Why is Superscript so much more picky than Subscript? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Superscript[G, {a, b}]` would be the right way to go I assume.

Comment: Shouldn't the sum return `G^(1,1) + G^(1,2) + G^(2,1) + G^(2,2)` instead of `4 G^(a,b)`?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this will work for you:

```
MakeBoxes[Superscript[b_, x_, y__], form_] ^:=
  ToBoxes[Superscript[b, Row[{x, y}]], form]
```

Example:

```
Sum[Superscript[G, a, b], {a, 1, 2}, {b, 1, 2}]
```

> $G^{11}+G^{12}+G^{21}+G^{22}$